# group-by seemingly changes order of range

Tags: algorithm, clojure, range

I'm trying to rewrite `distinct` for problem #56 on `4clojure.org`, and I have a working solution but I'm playing around with others.

I'm confused why my most recent attempt is failing the last unit test:

```
;; unit tests:
;; (= (__ [1 2 1 3 1 2 4]) [1 2 3 4])
;; (= (__ [:a :a :b :b :c :c]) [:a :b :c])
;; (= (__ '([2 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 3])) '([2 4] [1 2] [1 3]))
;; (= (__ (range 50)) (range 50))

;; most recent attempt
(fn [xs] (keys (group-by identity xs))) ;; fails for (range 50)

;; what?!?!
(keys (group-by identity (range 50))) ;; => (0 32 1 33 2 34 3 35 4 36 5 37 6 38 7 39 8 40 9 41 10 42 11 43 12 44 13 45 14 46 15 47 16 48 17 49 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31)
```

What is the reason I'm getting this seemingly random order?

PS: here's the link to the problem, but I'm not sure if you can see it without an account http://www.4clojure.com/problem/56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group-by` returns a hash map for inputs where the function passed in returns sufficiently many distinct values.<sup>1</sup> Hash maps don't make any guarantees regarding key order during traversals.

---

<sup>1</sup> `group-by` starts off creating a transient array map, then adds new keys using `assoc!`. Array maps are automatically converted to hash maps when they grow beyond a certain size (8 entries as of Clojure 1.6.0). (For completeness, larger array maps can be created using `clojure.core/array-map`.)